# How to apply C# formatting in Codemirror editor?

Tags: javascript, c#, code-formatting, codemirror

How to apply C# formatting in Codemirror editor ? I found this [demo](http://codemirror.net/2/demo/formatting.html) in Codemirror editor but it only support html/js/css formatting .

Thanks

Comment: http://codemirror.net/mode/clike/index.html?

Comment: Thanks for your comment . I already check this link . but i want formatting editor code (C#).